# How can I figure out the distance from nearby subway entrances in NYC given a specific latitude/longitude?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, api, google-maps, geolocation

I've tried using the google places API, doing a nearby location search using the type `subway_station`, and this returns nearby locations. But the problem is that (a) they aren't labeled e.g. as the A train and (b) the nearby subway stations aren't necessarily the entrances to those stations, thus the measurement can be off by up to a couple hundred feet.

I found this data set which has the subway entrances, labeled properly, etc: 
https://nycopendata.socrata.com/Transportation/Subway-Entrances/drex-xx56/data

So now I'm just trying to decide the best way to utilize that data in my Rails / Postgres environment. Should I export the data and create models based on it, then use [location aware database queries](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#location-aware-database-queries) or go another route?

I'm primarily a front-end developer and this isn't my forte so any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I export the data and create models based on it, then use location aware database queries or go another route?

Basically yes.

As for "location aware database queries", Postgres has a spatial extension called [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/).

So you would need to export data from [Subway Entrances](https://nycopendata.socrata.com/Transportation/Subway-Entrances/drex-xx56/data), create geometries in your database and then run queries utilizing methods like [ST_DistanceSphere](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.3/ST_DistanceSphere.html)